# How to get the status code within the response in grpcurl?

Tags: grpc, grpcurl

I use grpcurl for grpc request. I have the following request:

```
grpcurl -plaintext -import-path C:/Users/username -proto file.proto <localhost:port > service_name/methode
```

The mentioned request will return the following response without the status code. How can I get the status code within the response?

```
{
  "id": "0000000000000",
  "name": "AAAAAAAAAA"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot (directly).

Error codes are part of the gRPC protocol metadata **not** the (user-defined) message(s).

With `gRPCurl`, you've a couple of ways to get the error code.

In Bash, you can use command's exit status:

```bash
grpcurl ...
echo $?
```

See:

- [Need documentation for gRPC error codes](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl/issues/214)
- See [gRPC canonical error codes](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.50.0/codes#Code)

Or you can use `gRPCurl`'s `-format-error` flag.

```
-format-error
        When a non-zero status is returned, format the response using the
        value set by the -format flag .
```